# mxnet standard installation error

Tags: 16.04, cuda

I want to config the `config.mk`file to use the `cuda`. I modified these options:

```
    USE_CUDA = 1
    ADD_LDFLAGS = /usr/local/cuda-8.0/lib64
    ADD_CFLAGS = /usr/local/cuda-8.0/lib64
    USE_CUDA_PATH = /usr/local/cuda 
    USE_CUDNN = 1
    USE_NVRTC = 1
```

while I run `make -j8`, I got the errors below:

```
    cd /home/wanger/MXNet/mxnet/dmlc-core; make libdmlc.a USE_SSE=1 config=/home/wanger/MXNet/mxnet/config.mk; cd /home/wanger/MXNet/mxnet
    /usr/local/cuda /bin/nvcc -std=c++11 -Xcompiler -D_FORCE_INLINES -g -O3 -ccbin g++  -Xcompiler "-DMSHADOW_FORCE_STREAM -Wall -O3 -I/home/wanger/MXNet/mxnet/mshadow/ -I/home/wanger/MXNet/mxnet/dmlc-core/include -fPIC -Iinclude -funroll-loops -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unknown-pragmas -msse3 -I/usr/local/cuda /include -DMSHADOW_USE_CBLAS=1 -DMSHADOW_USE_MKL=0 -DMSHADOW_RABIT_PS=0 -DMSHADOW_DIST_PS=0 -DMSDHADOW_USE_PASCAL=0 -DMXNET_USE_OPENCV=1 `pkg-config --cflags opencv` -fopenmp -DMSHADOW_USE_CUDNN=1 /usr/local/cuda-8.0/lib64 -DMXNET_USE_NVRTC=1" -M -MT build/src/ndarray/ndarray_function_gpu.o src/ndarray/ndarray_function.cu >build/src/ndarray/ndarray_function_gpu.d
    make[1]: Entering directory '/home/wanger/MXNet/mxnet/dmlc-core'
    /usr/local/cuda /bin/nvcc -std=c++11 -Xcompiler -D_FORCE_INLINES -g -O3 -ccbin g++  -Xcompiler "-DMSHADOW_FORCE_STREAM -Wall -O3 -I/home/wanger/MXNet/mxnet/mshadow/ -I/home/wanger/MXNet/mxnet/dmlc-core/include -fPIC -Iinclude -funroll-loops -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unknown-pragmas -msse3 -I/usr/local/cuda /include -DMSHADOW_USE_CBLAS=1 -DMSHADOW_USE_MKL=0 -DMSHADOW_RABIT_PS=0 -DMSHADOW_DIST_PS=0 -DMSDHADOW_USE_PASCAL=0 -DMXNET_USE_OPENCV=1 `pkg-config --cflags opencv` -fopenmp -DMSHADOW_USE_CUDNN=1 /usr/local/cuda-8.0/lib64 -DMXNET_USE_NVRTC=1" -M -MT build/src/optimizer/sgd_gpu.o src/optimizer/sgd.cu >build/src/optimizer/sgd_gpu.d
    /usr/local/cuda /bin/nvcc -std=c++11 -Xcompiler -D_FORCE_INLINES -g -O3 -ccbin g++  -Xcompiler "-DMSHADOW_FORCE_STREAM -Wall -O3 -I/home/wanger/MXNet/mxnet/mshadow/ -I/home/wanger/MXNet/mxnet/dmlc-core/include -fPIC -Iinclude -funroll-loops -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unknown-pragmas -msse3 -I/usr/local/cuda /include -DMSHADOW_USE_CBLAS=1 -DMSHADOW_USE_MKL=0 -DMSHADOW_RABIT_PS=0 -DMSHADOW_DIST_PS=0 -DMSDHADOW_USE_PASCAL=0 -DMXNET_USE_OPENCV=1 `pkg-config --cflags opencv` -fopenmp -DMSHADOW_USE_CUDNN=1 /usr/local/cuda-8.0/lib64 -DMXNET_USE_NVRTC=1" -M -MT build/src/operator/convolution_gpu.o src/operator/convolution.cu >build/src/operator/convolution_gpu.d
    /usr/local/cuda /bin/nvcc -std=c++11 -Xcompiler -D_FORCE_INLINES -g -O3 -ccbin g++  -Xcompiler "-DMSHADOW_FORCE_STREAM -Wall -O3 -I/home/wanger/MXNet/mxnet/mshadow/ -I/home/wanger/MXNet/mxnet/dmlc-core/include -fPIC -Iinclude -funroll-loops -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unknown-pragmas -msse3 -I/usr/local/cuda /include -DMSHADOW_USE_CBLAS=1 -DMSHADOW_USE_MKL=0 -DMSHADOW_RABIT_PS=0 -DMSHADOW_DIST_PS=0 -DMSDHADOW_USE_PASCAL=0 -DMXNET_USE_OPENCV=1 `pkg-config --cflags opencv` -fopenmp -DMSHADOW_USE_CUDNN=1 /usr/local/cuda-8.0/lib64 -DMXNET_USE_NVRTC=1" -M -MT build/src/operator/svm_output_gpu.o src/operator/svm_output.cu >build/src/operator/svm_output_gpu.d
    /usr/local/cuda /bin/nvcc -std=c++11 -Xcompiler -D_FORCE_INLINES -g -O3 -ccbin g++  -Xcompiler "-DMSHADOW_FORCE_STREAM -Wall -O3 -I/home/wanger/MXNet/mxnet/mshadow/ -I/home/wanger/MXNet/mxnet/dmlc-core/include -fPIC -Iinclude -funroll-loops -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unknown-pragmas -msse3 -I/usr/local/cuda /include -DMSHADOW_USE_CBLAS=1 -DMSHADOW_USE_MKL=0 -DMSHADOW_RABIT_PS=0 -DMSHADOW_DIST_PS=0 -DMSDHADOW_USE_PASCAL=0 -DMXNET_USE_OPENCV=1 `pkg-config --cflags opencv` -fopenmp -DMSHADOW_USE_CUDNN=1 /usr/local/cuda-8.0/lib64 -DMXNET_USE_NVRTC=1" -M -MT build/src/operator/leaky_relu_gpu.o src/operator/leaky_relu.cu >build/src/operator/leaky_relu_gpu.d
    /usr/local/cuda /bin/nvcc -std=c++11 -Xcompiler -D_FORCE_INLINES -g -O3 -ccbin g++  -Xcompiler "-DMSHADOW_FORCE_STREAM -Wall -O3 -I/home/wanger/MXNet/mxnet/mshadow/ -I/home/wanger/MXNet/mxnet/dmlc-core/include -fPIC -Iinclude -funroll-loops -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unknown-pragmas -msse3 -I/usr/local/cuda /include -DMSHADOW_USE_CBLAS=1 -DMSHADOW_USE_MKL=0 -DMSHADOW_RABIT_PS=0 -DMSHADOW_DIST_PS=0 -DMSDHADOW_USE_PASCAL=0 -DMXNET_USE_OPENCV=1 `pkg-config --cflags opencv` -fopenmp -DMSHADOW_USE_CUDNN=1 /usr/local/cuda-8.0/lib64 -DMXNET_USE_NVRTC=1" -M -MT build/src/operator/lrn_gpu.o src/operator/lrn.cu >build/src/operator/lrn_gpu.d
    /usr/local/cuda /bin/nvcc -std=c++11 -Xcompiler -D_FORCE_INLINES -g -O3 -ccbin g++  -Xcompiler "-DMSHADOW_FORCE_STREAM -Wall -O3 -I/home/wanger/MXNet/mxnet/mshadow/ -I/home/wanger/MXNet/mxnet/dmlc-core/include -fPIC -Iinclude -funroll-loops -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unknown-pragmas -msse3 -I/usr/local/cuda /include -DMSHADOW_USE_CBLAS=1 -DMSHADOW_USE_MKL=0 -DMSHADOW_RABIT_PS=0 -DMSHADOW_DIST_PS=0 -DMSDHADOW_USE_PASCAL=0 -DMXNET_USE_OPENCV=1 `pkg-config --cflags opencv` -fopenmp -DMSHADOW_USE_CUDNN=1 /usr/local/cuda-8.0/lib64 -DMXNET_USE_NVRTC=1" -M -MT build/src/operator/fully_connected_gpu.o src/operator/fully_connected.cu >build/src/operator/fully_connected_gpu.d
    /bin/sh: 1: /usr/local/cuda: Permission denied
    Makefile:184: recipe for target 'build/src/ndarray/ndarray_function_gpu.o' failed
    make: *** [build/src/ndarray/ndarray_function_gpu.o] Error 126
    make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
    /bin/sh: 1: /usr/local/cuda: Permission denied
    /bin/sh: 1: /usr/local/cuda: Permission denied
    Makefile:184: recipe for target 'build/src/optimizer/sgd_gpu.o' failed
    make: *** [build/src/optimizer/sgd_gpu.o] Error 126
    Makefile:184: recipe for target 'build/src/operator/convolution_gpu.o' failed
    make: *** [build/src/operator/convolution_gpu.o] Error 126
    /bin/sh: 1: /usr/local/cuda: Permission denied
    /bin/sh: 1: /usr/local/cuda: Permission denied
    Makefile:184: recipe for target 'build/src/operator/svm_output_gpu.o' failed
    make: *** [build/src/operator/svm_output_gpu.o] Error 126
    Makefile:184: recipe for target 'build/src/operator/lrn_gpu.o' failed
    make: *** [build/src/operator/lrn_gpu.o] Error 126
    /bin/sh: 1: /usr/local/cuda: Permission denied
    Makefile:184: recipe for target 'build/src/operator/fully_connected_gpu.o' failed
    make: *** [build/src/operator/fully_connected_gpu.o] Error 126
    make[1]: 'libdmlc.a' is up to date.
    make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/wanger/MXNet/mxnet/dmlc-core'
    /bin/sh: 1: /usr/local/cuda: Permission denied
    Makefile:184: recipe for target 'build/src/operator/leaky_relu_gpu.o' failed
    make: *** [build/src/operator/leaky_relu_gpu.o] Error 126
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line

```
/bin/sh: 1: /usr/local/cuda: Permission denied
```

Suggests that your issue lies in incorrectly configured permissions for the directory `/usr/local/cuda`. You seem to try to execute it, as if it was a command file. What you most probably wanted is to execute `/usr/local/cuda/bin/nvcc`.

Edit your makefile so that the CUDA command reads `/usr/local/cuda/bin/nvcc` (note there is no space between "cuda" and "bin") and try again.